# RestKit CoreData hangs during unit test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am in the process of trying to get a test working for a service class that uses Restkit to perform various CoreData and JSON mapping operations related to the needs of our application. The service works fine when run via an iphone simulator deployment, but hangs when run via the context of a unit test.

It looks to be related to thread usage in Restkit as I have been able to narrow it down to the following class and method call. Basically, the performBlockAndWait never returns. I am very new to the objective c world (not to development in general) so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Restkit Class: RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache

Method:

```
- (NSSet *)managedObjectsWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity
                attributeValues:(NSDictionary *)attributeValues
         inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext

...

    // test hangs on this fetch call
    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }];
```

I am setting up my CoreData test stack with the following:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:NSClassFromString(@"EventServiceTests")];
NSLog(@"Found bundle: %@", bundle);

NSString *bundlePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"EventDataModel" ofType:@"momd"];
NSLog(@"Creating model from path: %@", bundlePath);

NSURL *momURL = [NSURL URLWithString:bundlePath];
NSLog(@"URL for model: %@", momURL);

NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];

RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

    NSLog(@"Initializing the Core Data stack...");
    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSString* dataStorePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"EventDataModel.dat"];
    NSLog(@"Persistent store file path: %@", dataStorePath);

    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: dataStorePath];

    if (![managedObjectStore.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSBinaryStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Issue creating persitent store: %2@", error);
    }

    NSAssert(managedObjectStore.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);

    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    NSLog(@"Setting the default store shared instance to: %@", managedObjectStore);
    [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

NSLog(@"Configuring the object manager...");
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://eventconsole.eng.techtarget.com/"]];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

NSLog(@"Setting shared manager instance to: %@", objectManager);
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
```

Then executing the request operation using:

```
NSString* url = UPCOMING_EVENTS_URL_PATH;
NSLog(@"Attempting to get upcoming events from url: %@", url);
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:url parameters:nil
        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully loaded %@ upcoming events",
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)[mappingResult count]] );
            returnVal = TRUE;
        }
        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error loading upcoming events: %@", error);
            returnVal = FALSE;
        }
 ];
```

and the actual test code:

```
NSLog(@"Executing testLoadAttendees...");
[_eventService loadAttendees:@"2269"];
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0f];
NSOperationQueue* queue = [RKObjectRequestOperation responseMappingQueue];
[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
```

Comment: How are you setting up your test environment (creating the Core Data stack)?

Comment: updated post to include sample test setup and service method usage of Restkit

Comment: I should really ask what you are trying to prove with your test - it looks like that your server works and that RestKit works. Unit tests shouldn't be used for either of these things.

Comment: The plan is to use these more as integration tests to ensure the  involved systems are functioning properly with the goal of automating them via a continuous integration style build process that runs a couple of times a day. Also, being new to xcode, objective-c, etc, I just want to try and understand how the testing support works in general. Assertions and such will be added, but at this point, I am just trying to get the method to execute and insert records into CoreData. I agree that in the purist sense of a 'unit test' I am not testing the Service in isolation.

Comment: Ok, so you need to do some research before deciding how to proceed: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=xcode+unittest+asynchronous

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution using one of the utility test classes provided by RestKit.

```
RKTestNotificationObserver *observer =
    [RKTestNotificationObserver 
         notificationObserverForName:RKObjectRequestOperationDidFinishNotification
                              object:nil];
observer.timeout = 60;
[observer addObserver];

NSLog(@"Executing testLoadAttendees...");
[_eventService loadAttendees:@"2269"];

[observer waitForNotification];
```

which I wrapped in a utility method:

```
- (void)executeAndTimeoutAfterSeconds:(int) timeoutSeconds usingBlock:(void(^)())block
{
    RKTestNotificationObserver *observer =
        [RKTestNotificationObserver notificationObserverForName:RKObjectRequestOperationDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    [observer addObserver];
    observer.timeout = timeoutSeconds;
    block();
    [observer waitForNotification];
}
```

so test are now executed using:

```
[self executeAndTimeoutAfterSeconds:60 usingBlock:^ {
    NSLog(@"Executing testLoadAttendees...");
    [_eventService loadAttendees:@"2269"];
}];
```