# RestKit Testing RKManagedObjectRequestOperation in XCode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, restkit, restkit-0.20

XCode 5 seems to have removed the ability to run headless "Logic Tests", and instead forces all of your tests to run with your actual application bundle loaded along side it (ala the old "Application Tests").  As a result, my actual `AppDelegate` initialization of RestKit happens before my tests get to run, which causes problems.

I have been trying to follow the Core Data test patterns as outlined [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Tests/Logic/Network/RKManagedObjectRequestOperationTest.m?source=cc) but they aren't cooperating, I suspect because there is already a configuration/instantiation of RestKit set up in my `AppDelegate`.  Is there any guidance on how to test remote Core Data RestKit operations using the default testing paradigm imposed in XCode 5?  RKObjectRequestOperation tests just the same, it's only the Core Data version that gives me issues.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question allowed me to test my `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` calls in a way very similar to standard `RKObjectRequestOperation` calls.

[RestKit CoreData hangs during unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694570/restkit-coredata-hangs-during-unit-test)